# Check length using String method length

Tags: string, methods

This has been bugging me for three days. I'm attempting to read text from a text field, check the length of the value is greater than zero (using the String method length), then create a loop. If the length is not greater than zero, I have to set an error message and an error flag (boolean variable to true). I've dug into the documentation for the String method but I can't seem to get length() to work for me. You can see my experimenting with the code. First time posting, sorry if I'm getting this wrong.

```
private void setShipmentProperties() {
    ship.setEmployeeNum(empNumTF.getText());
    if(ship.setEmployeeNum(String(length()) < 0)) {
        isDataEntryError = true;
        msgLbl.setText("Pay rate must be a numeric " + "value: 1, 2, 3...");
    }
    ship.setShipmentNum(shipNumTF.getText(this.length()));
    if(this.length() < 0) {
        isDataEntryError = true;
        msgLbl.setText("Pay rate must be a numeric " + "value: 1, 2, 3...");
    }
    ship.setSupplierName(supplTF.getText());
     if(ship.length() < 0) {
        isDataEntryError = true;
        msgLbl.setText("Pay rate must be a numeric " + "value: 1, 2, 3...");
    }
}
```

Comment: use this.length instead of this.length()

Comment: I assume ship is a class of yours and setEmployeeNum is a method that takes a string as its parameter. But immediately after calling it, you call it again with whatever `String(length()) < 0)` yields, which isn't a string. 
Why not test the string before you pass it to your class' setters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Ship is an object that eventually gathers all of this info to pass it to another object.

Answer (score 0):

A length can't be < 0. The length of a string can't be less than zero.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's unclear. The length needs to be checked if the value is greater than zero using the String method length. If it isn't greater than zero, I need an if loop defining an error message and an error flag.

Comment: I'm still lost. You're checking for < 0. I think you need to check for 0.